# How to burn PIC hex from arduino?

Tags: arduino, pic, bootloader, arduino-esp8266, pic18

I'm new on this field ...

I have a Arduino ESP8266 connected to a PIC18F trought UART2, I wonder if already  there is something out there to send the HEX file from the ESP to the pic and burn the firmware

PS: the ESP already has the HEX file stored in memory

[image]

Comment: You wan't to act your ARDUINO as a PIC programmer? Otherwise you need a bootloader in your PIC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use In-Circuit Serial Programming™ (ICSP™)

Find an appropriate guide on how to program based on your PIC

https://www.microchip.com/doclisting/TechDoc.aspx?type=Programming